# Application name as first activity

Tags: android

I switched in manifest manually between activities because I made new activity that needed to be first. Everything works fine, but in the apps screen in my launcher where I see all apps below my app icon i see the name of the first activity "SplashScreen", but when I uninstall in or go to my apps I see that the name is OK.

My manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.myapp.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.myapp.MainScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.myapp.Cameras"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_cameras"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: don't give your splashscreen a label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen"
```

that is the name being used.
you can just delete this line (and all the label from the other activities) and let all activities use the application name `@string/app_name`

Answer (score 1):

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.myapp.SplashScreen"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```

This should display the Application name